# doing multiple tasks letting user know when a task complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

so I'm creating a asp.net webforms application, and now i have this page where i have to do multiple checks and data manipulation of multiple tables.

Now I want to show the user the different steps that need to be taken do complete their request and show a green check or whatever when one step is complete. All these things happen after the user clicks a button ofcourse.

My problem is, I don't have the slightest clue of how to get started with this. Should i use Threads? Async calls? Something else?

Any advice given is greatly appreciated!

cheers

Comment: asp.net wizard control ?

Answer (score 0):

As Zey says, you could use something like a ASP .NET wizard control that sits on just one page.

See here for an example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/01/21/walkthrough-wizard-control-in-asp-net.aspx

Alternatively, you could just use AJAX updates and show each sub-page in a bigger page and render each sub-page's contents dynamically.

Comment: I checked out the wizard control but I don't think it's what I am looking for..
I want to have 1 page with a list of all the steps that need to be taken (for example. Check users). If the users are checked in the database i want to show a image that shows that this step is complete. The only thing the user has to do is push a button on the top of the page. He doesn't has to fill in different forms.

Comment: That sounds like you could just use a line of ASP .NET image buttons along the top of your page. When they're clicked they change to a tick?

Comment: I have to use only 1 button, but thanks anyway for your feedback!
I'm trying to do it with a thread and a timer at the moment.